# How to write a message using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, linkedin-api

I want to know how I can write a message on linkedin to send my connections. I've done using send keys but it just write only one line I also have used Keys.Shift + keys.enter but it can only write two lines. is there any any way to write a full message in multiple lines using selenium.. to writing a new line it is also doesn't work "\n"

Please let me know is there any way....

I have tried below code:-

```
description = browser.find_element_by_id("compose-message") 
description .send_keys('Hi' , Keys.SHIFT + Keys.ENTER, 'How are you')       
description .send_keys('Hi' "\n" 'How are you "\n" it is me')
```

both don't work to write multiple lines

Comment: show what you have tried till now?

Comment: description  = browser.find_element_by_id("compose-message")
description .send_keys('Hi' , Keys.SHIFT + Keys.ENTER,  'How are you')

description .send_keys('Hi' "\n"  'How are you "\n" it is me')

both don't work to write multiple lines

Comment: The reason \n isn't working is that you are using ' and ' to enclose your strings. description .send_keys("Hi' \n 'How are you \n it is me")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is just need to uncheck the "press enter to send" in the message box nothing to do anything it works.. One last thing is. it doesn't work on Firefox when sending a long message just use Chrome webdriver

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me...

```
description = browser.find_element_by_id("compose-message")
description.send_keys("Hi\nHow are you\n it is me")
```

Comment: It just write "Hi" \n use to write new line using enter key but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the page looks like and there is a typo above you have a space between description and send_keys e.g.

```
description .send_keys('')
```

should be

```
description.send_keys('')
```

I also don't understand why you what to use shift enter (perhaps to add a new line?) If so have you tried

```
description.send_keys('Hi,\nHow are you')
```

Where `'\n'` is a newline delimiter

Comment: '\n' it doesn't work to write a new line but you can write new line using Shift + Enter keys but it can write just 2 lines not a complete message